# Как сделать URL ссылки не нажимаемыми?

Tags: java, android, textview

Есть `TextView` в котором имеются несколько ссылок. При нажатии на TextView появляется PopupMenu. Но в тоже время происходит переход на сайт. Убрать атрибут "autoLink" нельзя - не появится PopupMenu. Вопрос: Как сделать ссылки в TextView не нажимаемыми? Знаю, что нужно использовать `LinkMovementMethod()`, только не знаю как.

Пробую что-то типа:

```
@Override
   public boolean onTouchEvent(TextView widget , Spannable buffer , MotionEvent event ){
     return false;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Есть решение сделать это через разметку TextView:

```
<TextView
  ...
  android:linksClickable="false"
  .../>
```